# Interface builder unable to determine type of "mainmenu.xib"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

Using Xcode 5.1. on OSX 10.9.1 I go to create a new project. OSX > Application > Cocoa Application.

It's an empty app. I click build. I get one error:

> Interface builder was unable to determine the type of "MainMenu.xib".

Clicking on `MainMenu.xib` shows me a blank screen, basically ready for me to write code. Not the friendly drag and drop interface I've used before when building apps.

On the right side bar, I notice the Type is `Default - Abstract Interface Builder XIB`. On other working projects (created before upgrading to Xcode 5), the type is `Default - Interface Builder Cocoa XIB`.

The only link online I've found that relates to this issue is [this one](http://prod.lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2013/Dec/msg00072.html), which indicates it's some sort of template problem, but doesn't elaborate on *what* the problem is or *how* to fix it.

Thoughts?

Comment: I have edited your post, I assume you mean OSX 10.9.1 not 9.1. if there is a mistake please rollback.

Comment: yes that makes sense. i had assumed the 'x' in 'osx' stood for the 10. edit stands. thanks.

Comment: actually, just realized i had asked this question twice (oops) and had worked out an answer myself. not sure how to mark as a duplicate, but here is the same post with a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23924536/xcode-interface-builder-xib-compiler-error

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by opening "Xcode-Macintosh HD" instead of "Xcode- Developer" after searching it from spotlight. (Spotlight is the magnifying glass in the top right)